# How to have chapter title on its own page in a twocolumn document (KOMA class scrbook)?

Tags: chapters, koma-script, two-column

I am writing a document using the `scrbook` class from `KOMA-script`. My problem is that I want a `chapter` command that will display the chapter title centered horizontally and vertically on a blank page, whether I am using the options `twocolumn` or not. I already have some code that works fine when it's a one-column layout.

So my immediate problem is trying to find one that works with `\KOMAoptions{twocolumn}` and then I can work out the rest, probably using some conditional code so that it works whether it is two-column or not (is what I'm thinking).

Here is the (working) code I use for a normal one-column document:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterheadstartvskip {}{\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterheadendvskip {}{\vfill\clearpage}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chaptermarkformat {}{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterformat {}{}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterlinesformat {mmm} {%
  #2\par
{\centering #3}
}
```

When I switched to a two-column layout with `\KOMAoptions{twocolumn}` I found out that it didn't work like that anymore. I thought it came from the fact that `\clearpage` after all will only clear one page, but even adding multiple `\null\newpage` wouldn't add a new page, instead it just added some white space below the chapter title.

I tried to use `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` switch but it doesn't work inside the redefinition of the various `\chapter` commands. Here is the MWE to illustrates:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twocolumn} 

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterheadstartvskip {}{%
\onecolumn
\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterheadendvskip {}{%
\vfill\clearpage
\twocolumn %if this omitted, chapter text simply disappears
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chaptermarkformat {}{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterformat {}{}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterlinesformat {mmm} {%
  #2\par
{\centering #3}
}

\begin{document}

%Works fine, display "Test" vertically centered
\onecolumn
\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill
Test
\vfill\clearpage
\twocolumn

%Works fine, display "Test" vertically centered
\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill
Test
\vfill\cleardoublepage

%Doesn't display "Chapter" on a single page horizontally and vertically centered.
\chapter{Chapter}   
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: chapter page of the MWE]

How can I achieve the desired effect?

A secondary question I have is that if I omit the `\twocolumn` switch from `\chapterheadendvskip`, then the chapter text simply disappears, why?

Comment: Do you want the effect of `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: That works fine in the document, but not for my issue.
When I try replacing `\clearpage` by `\cleardoublepage`, with or without the `\onecolumn`, `\twocolumn` switch, it changes nothing for how the chapter title Chapter is displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the `style` of section level `chapter` to `part`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions{twocolumn} 

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\chaptermarkformat {}{}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterformat {}{}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=part,
  innerskip=0pt,
  beforeskip=\fill,
  afterskip=\fill
]{chapter}

\begin{document}
% Works fine, display "Test" vertically centered
\onecolumn
\vspace*{-\topskip}\vfill
Test
\vfill\clearpage
\twocolumn

\chapter{Chapter}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was also using the following code to increase the size of the chapter title:

`\DeclareDocumentCommand\chapterlinesformat {mmm} {%
  #2\par
  \adjustbox{center}{%
      \adjustbox{minipage=8cm, scale=3, max width=20cm}{\centering #3}%
    }%
}`

But switching `chapter` to `part` style means it doesn't use `chapterlinesformat` anymore, and there doesn't seem to be a `partlinesformat` or equivalent according to the documentation. Any idea?

Comment: No, unfortualy there is not a `\partlinesformat` yet. But I have added an alternative suggestion to your question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340986/43317) that should work with `twocolumn` too. But you will get warnings.